# Problem in using Invers Kinematics

Tags: rigging, armature, inverse-kinematics

[image]

Please help me, how can i fix it ???

Comment: you need to rotate the pole angle in the IK settings

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, the old twisting mesh problem, it's super easy to fix, just apply the armature pose as the rest pose and it will be fixed

This happens because for some weird reason, when you add IK to a bone it rotates 180 degrees but you wouldn't notice

[image: apply pose]

Before doing this make sure you have all the bones in the rest position or else any pose that you have made will stay like that as the default,
a little tip when doing IK: parent the pole target to the ik bonee, so you wont need to be animating it, that just saves you an extra step

just apply the pose as rest pose and that's it :D